# Meaning of "summer" and "winter" in Australian English

Tags: meaning, australian-english

What is the meaning of "summer" (and "winter") in modern Australian English? It means cold time, but in June, July and August, or warm time, but in December, January and February?

Comment: Are you asking when summer and winter occur in Australia or what words they use to describe summer and winter?

Comment: I'm asking what do _English_ colonizers name "summer".

Comment: The English have stopped colonising Australia. The Australian summer is when it is warm in Australia; the Australian winter is when it is cold in Australia. The same is true for all countries.

Comment: What do you mean by the *but* when you say "cold time, *but* in June, July, and August"? The *but* makes it sound like you think June, July, and August are not cold. And same about "warm time, but...", the *but* makes it seem like you think December, January, and February are not warm.

Comment: You're saying December et. al. is always winter, which as Australia proves, it isn't.  They use our northern hemisphere calendar because it would be confusing otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Australian summer is when it is warm in Australia; the Australian winter is when it is cold in Australia. The same is true for all countries. – [Greybeard](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/330962/greybeard)

Comment: Absolutely. Winter occurs when the part of the earth you are talking about is tilted away from the sun, summer occurs when it is tilted towards the sun. The tropics don't really get summer and winter their seasons are a bit different. When it's summer in the northern hemisphere it's winter in the southern and vice versa. I used to have an aunt who'd lived in Melbourne and she told me that the South winds in July were really cold. As a British person that sounded odd in so many ways but it's obvious why it's so.